# How to replace cur_dat() with pick()?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I understand `cur_data()` should be replaced by `pick()`. How would I rewrite this? `mutate(normalized_mean_speed = mean_speed / cur_data()$mean_speed[1:3])`

I wish to divide `mean_speed` for each year by the average of the first three years, in order to plot progress over the years.

The entire code for this part (that I suppose could be simplified to make it easier to read) is this:

```
data_raw |>
  group_by(event, 
           year= year(event_date)) |> 
  filter(year_rank > 0) |> 
  top_n(10, speed) |> 
  arrange(year, -speed) |> 
  select(year, year_rank, distance, speed, event) |> 
  group_by(event, 
           year) |> 
  filter(year >= 1990, event != "marathon" & event != "72h") |> 
  summarise(mean_speed = mean(speed)) |> 
  mutate(normalized_mean_speed = mean_speed / cur_data()$mean_speed[1:3]) |> 
  mutate(moving_average = rollmean(normalized_mean_speed, 
                                   k = 5, 
                                   na.pad = TRUE)) |> 
  mutate(event = fct_reorder(event, mean_speed)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(year, 
             normalized_mean_speed, 
             colour = fct_reorder(event, -mean_speed))) +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.15, se = F) +
  geom_line(aes(year, moving_average), 
            linetype = "dotted", 
            linewidth = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, 
             linetype="dashed", 
             color = "grey", size=0.5) +
  labs(title = paste0("Average Top 10 Per Year - ", sex),
       subtitle = "normalized to 1990-1992 average",
       color = "Events",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Normalized Mean Speed") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1990, 2023),
                     breaks = seq(1990, 2023, 5),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))
                     ) +
  theme_ultra +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
  facet_wrap(~fct_reorder(event, -mean_speed), 
             shrink = TRUE
             )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pick.html) state:

> `pick()` provides a way to select a subset of your columns using tidyselect. It returns a data frame... This is useful for functions that take data frames as inputs.

In your example, you are calculating the normalized mean speed by sorting speed in descending order by group and taking the top three rows. Instead, you could use [`dplyr::slice_max()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html). This takes a data frame as input so it's a good candidate for `pick()`.

Here's an example with the `iris` dataset using the deprecated `cur_data()`:

```r
iris |>
    group_by(Species) |>
    reframe(
        mean_petal_length = cur_data() |>
            slice_max(Petal.Length, n = 3) |>
            pull(Petal.Length) |>
            mean(),
        normalized_petal_length = Petal.Length / mean_petal_length
    )
```

As `slice_max()` takes a data frame, we provide it one with `cur_data()`. But then we throw that all away because we're only interested in the `Petal.Length` column, which we [`pull()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html). With `pick()`, we still need to `pull()`, but at least we can just pass `slice_max()` a data frame with one column, the one we're interested in (and the grouping column which comes automatically):

```r
iris |>
    group_by(Species) |>
    reframe(
        mean_petal_length = pick(Petal.Length) |>
            slice_max(Petal.Length, n = 3) |>
            pull(Petal.Length) |>
            mean(),
        normalized_petal_length = Petal.Length / mean_petal_length
    )


# # A tibble: 150 × 3
#    Species mean_petal_length normalized_petal_length
#    <fct>               <dbl>                   <dbl>
#  1 setosa               1.77                   0.792
#  2 setosa               1.77                   0.792
#  3 setosa               1.77                   0.736
#  4 setosa               1.77                   0.849
#  5 setosa               1.77                   0.792
#  6 setosa               1.77                   0.962
#  7 setosa               1.77                   0.792
#  8 setosa               1.77                   0.849
#  9 setosa               1.77                   0.792
# 10 setosa               1.77                   0.849
```

The output is the same in both cases.

Comment: I like the way you answer the question, with reference and explanation, cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for thorough explanation! I took the mean of the mean_speed for the first three years, rather than the top three mean_speed, though. But I could use pick(year, mean_speed) and then slice_min(year) rather than slice_max(mean_speed).

As I am using mean_speed further down the pipe, do I need to add that in reframe() as well? I didn't have to with mutate().

Comment: @DanielWestergren no the `reframe()` was just for this example - you don't need it.

Comment: Very good example.  This isn't necessarily better but with `nest_by` one can use `data` insead of `cur_data()` or `pick` : `iris |>
  nest_by(Species) |>
  reframe(data, 
      mean_petal_length = slice_max(data, Petal.Length, n = 3) |>
        pull(Petal.Length) |>
        mean(),
      normalized_petal_length = Petal.Length / mean_petal_length
  )`